# AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException with Method security using jwt authentication

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, jwt

I followed this tutorial to get jwt based authentication into my spring boot application:
https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/03/08/securing-rest-api-spring-security
However I am using Kotlin.

According to the tutorial I have added a `TokenAuthenticationFilter` which is extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` to the filter chain in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

```
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) = http.apply {
        //...
        authenticationProvider(authProvider)
        addFilterBefore(tokenAuthFilter, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter::class.java)
        //...
```

In the `successfulAuthentication` method this filter will properly set the credentials:

```
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
```

The filterchain is executed for methods in controllers without method security.
Login works, I get a jwt token, and when I put it inside the Authorization header of requests, I get the proper AuthenticationPrincipal - so testing with an endpoint I get the logged in user back successfully

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    fun whoami(@AuthenticationPrincipal user: User?) = user;
```

However as soon as I try to use method-security on some endpoint

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('UploadArtifact')")
    fun uploadArtifact(
        @RequestParam("artifact", required = true) artifact: MultipartFile,
        @Valid @RequestParam("meta", required = true) request: UploadArtifactRequest
    ): ResponseEntity<Any> {
    //...
```

I get an AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException

> org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException:
> An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext     at
> org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:333)
> ~[spring-security-core-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]   at
> org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:200)
> ~[spring-security-core-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]   at
> org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:58)
> ~[spring-security-core-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> [###package name redacted###].ArtifactController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$99d39dee.uploadArtifact()
> ~[main/:na]
> ...

I set breakpoints

- at the start of the `TokenAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication` method.
- in `ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter`

Apparently two `ApplicationFilterChain` instances run on the request, both of which containa delegating proxy chain named 'springSecurityFilterChain'

1. The `ApplicationFilterChain` that is executed first is started from `StandardWrapperValve.java`.
   Its springSecurityFilterChain does not contain the TokenAuthenticationFilter . The AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException exception is thrown here.
2. The second `ApplicationFilterChain` is started from `ApplicationDispatcher.java`.
   Its springSecurityFilterChain does contain the `TokenAuthenticationFilter` and successfulAuthentication is reached, but that is obviousely useless at that point.

So now I have two independent questions:

- How can I ensure that the authentication happens in time? Should there be two filter chains - or did I mess something up with configuration?
- generally: should I even use that kind of tutorial - or is there a better way to integrate stateless authentication with jwt in 2021 into spring boot application?